# Java 8 and Java time

Tags: java, java-8, codenameone

I know the default Java library for [Codename One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codename_One) is now Java 8 and I am also compiling locally with Java 8.

I am trying to use the new [java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) added in Java 8 ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)).  I see the following error at compile time:

> : error: package java.time does not exist

Are java.time classes not included in Codename One’s Java 8 port? Should I be using the older Java date instead ? I am not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: Probably you are using an IDE that has a "compatibility mode" to work for a lower JDK version. You should disable it.

Comment: `compiling locally` -- using `javac` from command prompt or from IDE ?

Comment: I am not familiar with Codename One. But I can say that the java.time framework is part of Java 8 Standard Edition. So every implementation of Java SE must include these classes. Certainly present with the [Oracle implementation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and the [OpenJDK implementation](http://openjdk.java.net).

Comment: `javac -version` will shed some light, but must be an older JDK

Comment: The keyword for Codename One is "subset of" Java 8. If we included the whole Java 8 the rt.jar alone is 63MB. Since native compilation increases the size usually by a factor of 8 this would be a problem even with optimizations... The best attempts we saw for full JDK support ended up with a 50MB hello world. We produce 3MB binaries. Having said that I would love for someone to package this in a cn1lib: https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Codename One includes a subset of the Java 1.8 classes. I don't think that Java Time classes are included, CN1 has its own classes which are a subset of an earlier Java version (maybe 1.5, I don't recall).

The Javadocs for all the CN1 classes are here: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A quick check on [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) reveals: yes, java8 does include a package *java.time*.

Thus the fact that your setup gives you that error can **only** be rooted in some sort of misconfiguration in your setup.

A typical thing that happens with eclipse: you have set the "compiler compatibility" level to 1.8 - but within the build path setup for your project you are **not** pointing to a 1.8 JRE, but maybe to a 1.7 one.

Thus, the answer is: check with JDK/JRE is used within your setup to determine the available libraries. So even when one doesn't see compiler errors for Java8 syntax ... when pointing to the wrong JRE/JDK libraries things still wont work.